# Using Ubuntu 20.04 and phpmyadmin on php 7.4 how to setup non localhost connection

Tags: networking, server, ssh, apache2, php

I am using a HEADLESS cli server so there will not be a gui on localhost for this, SSH won't allow a browser to work, and adding an xservice for remote display really is not worth it for this server.
I read a depreciated article that you can allow subnet connections but the structure to the .conf is no longer valid using this configuration as it is updated.

What I need to know is where to find phpmyadmin.conf and what lines to add to allow my subnet to connect from a remote web browser.
Searching the stack of folders I find `phpmyadmin.conf` in:

```
./etc/dbconfig-common/
./etc/apache2/conf-available/
./etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
```

I need sudo to access the one in the dbconfig-common and I see localhost but it is not clear if that is for the service to access itself.
In the following folders, I do not see where localhost is the only allowed connection so not sure what to change there.

In normal desktop mode, this would not be an issue but when this is a server with only cli via SSH I do not see why there is not a clear document to fix this as I am sure no one would add a desktop to a headless server to do this, defeats the idea of a headless server.

Thanks for the help,

Requested contents from Apache's `000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

#vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

or default.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php7.0-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Not sure which one is active. Both seem to be discussed in the search results I have found.

So I think I fixed the formatting issues the site has with your request.
The virtualhost section is not commented out but to apply the proper formating I had to comment it out so it shows.

Too bad, there is not a way to add this exactly as it shows in a file. that and no one has been polite enough to explain how.

Results of server Unit mariadb.service could not be found.

Trying to clean up to reinstall I get this

```
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 474814
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'
Failed to preset unit: File mysql.service: Link has been severed
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on mysql.service: No such file or directory
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@panasonic:/var/run/mysqld#
```

```
root@panasonic:/var/run/mysqld# sudo apt install mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  galera-3 libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient21 libsnappy1v5
  libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-client-10.3 mariadb-client-core-10.3 mariadb-common
  mariadb-server-10.3 mariadb-server-core-10.3 socat
Suggested packages:
  libclone-perl libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libsql-statement-perl mailx mariadb-test tinyca
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  galera-3 libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient21 libsnappy1v5
  libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-client-10.3 mariadb-client-core-10.3 mariadb-common mariadb-server
  mariadb-server-10.3 mariadb-server-core-10.3 socat
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/20.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 19.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 134419 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--remove):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
Failed to preset unit: File mysql.service: Link has been severed
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on mysql.service: No such file or directory
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@panasonic:/var/run/mysqld#
```

But removing attempts look like there is no `mysql-server-8.0` to remove.
Results of removal of mysql:

```
root@panasonic:/var/run/mysqld# sudo apt remove mysql-server-8.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-server-8.0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,481 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 134419 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--remove):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
Failed to preset unit: File mysql.service: Link has been severed
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on mysql.service: No such file or directory
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@panasonic:/var/run/mysqld#
```

This all seems so conflicted.

Comment: There is a remarkable amount of documentation for all things Apache-related all over the web. The trick is knowing what questions to ask. With that said, I have three questions for you: what address are you typing in the browser to access the server? Do you see a different website or nothing at all? And can you update the question to include the contents of the Apache  `.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`? With this, it will be much easier to let you know what to change and, more importantly, why 

Comment: I am using a workstation to access 192.168.3.183   I get an error 404 when I try to connect to that address but info.php works. sure I can add the .conf there are several so just need to know which, that remarkable amount of information covers many versios and the folders keep changing per version.

Comment: It seems like my sql is the mariadb variant.  The results I find are for the mysql version and much of the folders do not match with Ubuntu 20 php 7.4  mariadb gives this    Server version: 10.3.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I see many results that almost do it but my structure is like this root@panasonic:/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d# ls
50-client.cnf  50-mysql-clients.cnf  50-mysqld_safe.cnf  50-server.cnf
This one nearly comes close https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766855/phpmyadmin-remote-access  But this is for mysql.

Comment: Doing that gives this   root@panasonic:/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d# sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 84
Server version: 10.3.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Ubuntu 20.04

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)
So it does not look to change things.

Comment: All of this is because I am following this instructable. https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-osticket-on-ubuntu-linux/#ex1

Comment: So following those remarkable numerous results my SQL seems to be completely broken as the commands are in one of the results no longer working and they if used can break a system using the latest version of OS apache MariaDB and PHP.  To bad my every search is not that full of exact matches

Comment: Are you trying to install osTicket or phpMyAdmin? I'm a bit confused about all the different config files you're looking at and modifying ...

Comment: Typing to install OsTicket, it is asking for a user name and password for the MySQL which I set up as root and a known password, the setup would not accept it so I tried to add phpmysql which results in 404 so I decided to follow the password reset information which has lead to trying to remove MySQL which will not remove or reinstall mysql.

Comment: PHP seems to still work

Comment: The PBX's are physical machines in the hospital and nursing homes, the Voice mail hazardously connects with Gmail and youtube to forward the VM to email.  We want to resolve that problem as about every 6 months we have to fix how these connect to those servers.  We want a time server for our uses to sync the clocks too.  A ticket system to make it faster to report issues.  "It is broken" is not a good explanation as many times I go in and find that broken is really a move of a port from one place to another.  A reload would not take much.

Comment: I need better scripts that use current systems commands and programs/plug-ins.

Comment: /opt/Xeams  So I want to use FTP to back this folder up before wiping the server again.  It is very odd that I can not copy files from the server to an empty folder that I created in windows. seems like a permission issue but I am logged in as the user, how do sudo I guess for ftp using windows.

Comment: These comments are getting very long ... you cannot use `sudo` with FTP. It would make more sense to use `tar` to make a single file, move it to a directory that can be accessed via the FTP, then copy it down. On the server, from the Xeams directory: `sudo tar -cvf xeams.tar *`. Then move it to the appropriate directory and set the permissions with `sudo chown`. From there you can copy it over.

Comment: I use google but I made a file chris.owen09 like my email for that xeams backup. I have backed up the virtual interface and the network settings file.  The r3est I think I Can do from scratch let me blast the OS.

Comment: So I reloaded. Where should I start with the osTicket, I can load lamp or lemp?  What is the better document to install ostickets?  Xeams is easy, the time server I am not sure about yet,  I need to do an SSL cert but had not looked into that.  I have the other files for a network setup.

Comment: Looking for a way to move this to chat ... but I don't see how. That said, [follow this step-by-step from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04) and *only* that one. Get your LAMP set up. Once it's done, then [download osTicket](https://osticket.com/download/) and put it in `/var/www/html`. Create a DB user, like in the answer below, then configure and install osTicket. That's it.

Comment: OK I will follow that, there are so many versions that I have tried.... have already installed webmin, and xeams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, based on the comments, seems to be that you're using `root` as the login for your SQL database. This is forbidden for a number of security reasons, so you will need to create a user account in MySQL (or MariaDB) that can be used by osTicket.

This is what you do:

1. On your server, connect to the database:

   ```
   sudo mysql
   ```
2. Create a database for osTicket:

   ```
   mysql> CREATE DATABASE `osticket` DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
   ```
3. Create a user for osTicket:

   ```
   mysql> CREATE USER 'ostkt'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to change* `ostkt` *to something you would prefer. Also change* `superSecretPassword!123` *to something that is better. If the database is on a different system than the web server, you will need to replace* `localhost` *with a percent sign. For example:*

   ```
   mysql> CREATE USER 'ostkt'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
   ```
4. Grant the new account full access to the new database:

   ```
   mysql> GRANT ALL ON `osticket`.* TO 'ostkt'@'localhost';
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to replace* `localhost` *with* `%` *if the database is on a different server than the web server.*
5. Provide the credentials to the osTicket configuration file
6. Continue setting up osTicket

As for "no one has been polite enough to explain how", do understand that AskUbuntu (and many other StackExchange sites) is powered by volunteers, not employees. People pick and choose the questions when they have free time and the requisite knowledge and ability to assist.

Hopefully with this answer, you can continue your installation of osTicket

Comment: unfortunately every result that I tried has not got me at ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
so MySQL won't even log in.  I tried to create a user for osTickets using the script I was following which is what caused the problem.  I could not get the cli scripts to make a user that would work and trying to add PHPMyAdmin to do the task was a failure, so that locked me out and I figured I would uninstall and re-install from scratch which has me at a broken mysql error.

Comment: Let's confirm that the database is running, then. What do you see when you type `sudo systemctl status mariadb` into the server? Please update the question with the output of that, as it will be very difficult to read as a comment.

Comment: Ok added the output from auoclean and install of maria also.

Comment: Why are you in the `/var/run/mysqld` directory? You didn't manually delete the `.sock` files ... did you? As for the DB ... do you have a preference? Installing MariaDB on a machine that has had MySQL installed will result in pain. Same goes for installing MySQL on a machine that had MariaDB installed. It is better to choose one or the other ...

Comment: I would like to know how to put the results in a clear code area for easy reading.  I have tried the buttons but they don't seem to work the way I want them, so much of the brackets get hidden  That seems to be important to show the proper format even if the file is not in the right format. a clipboard copy that shows a malformed file is important for diagnostics.  But if the format does not appear right, then you have to ask extra questions....

Comment: I was there trying to edit something several searches ago.  The info I followed was for mariadb but then things took a sideways fork when I could not get access to the user osTicket database.  The sole purpose is for XEAMS email for a panasonic pbx voice mail relay and a ticket system to report issues.  So I would like to install phpmyadmin but with the sql that works best with it and osTicket....

Comment: This server uses cli only so need this to work from a remote terminal.  Not really looking to add a gui and browser to the server.  That xwindow thing that can be viewed across the network.

Comment: I followed a instructable that said go there but it is empty

Comment: The problem here (for me) is that "too much" has been done to try and get something working. I don't know what you've changed, added, or attempted. It's not often I suggest starting over but, if you can get a fresh installation of Ubuntu, then this can all be done with some painless step-by-step instructions. That said, it looks as though you're doing all of this on the same server that hosts your PBX. If this is the case, then a fresh OS installation is probably not something that will easily happen.

Comment: "
Looking for a way to move this to chat ... but I don't see how. That said, follow this step-by-step from Digital Ocean and only that one. Get your LAMP set up. Once it's done, then download osTicket and put it in /var/www/html. Create a DB user, like in the answer below, then configure and install osTicket. That's it. – Matigo 23 hours ago
"  I had to re install php using parts of this document to get all the requied php bits osTicket needed,  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04.

Comment: So it works but I can not sign in... to osticket, I will search on that but after all of this it works as expected.

Comment: Due to a major bug in Ubuntu that I can not fix with the netmanager I have tried to repair and with many failures am looking at setting up a completely new build of the server and adding virtual to that, I am getting away from windows server as the OS that is running the virtual manager and will use a full Ubuntu setup for everything adding virtual servers.  So your idea about full start over will be used with your comments to fix it.  Thanks